# Access to componentParent from this.gridApi.ForEachNode

Tags: angular, grid

I need to select a default ag grid row based on the selected date which is present in the parent container. I am unable to refer to `componentParent` or 'this' from inside the node function

```
this.gridApi.forEachNode(function (node) {
     If(node.data.dueDate 
          ===this.parentContainer.selectedDueDate) {
                node.setSelected(true)
    }
});
```

I get `'this' is undefined` error. I am unable to get handle to `gridOptions` to use

```
gridOptions.context.componentParent.selectedDueDate
```

Any hint to get this working will be really appreciated.

Thanks
Sidd

Comment: Hi Sourav , The issue is not with the uppercase 'If'. I had just written the pseudocode to explain what I had done.I ll try your solution and let you know.

Comment: Alright check with my solution and kindly accept if it solved your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a typo `If(node.data.dueDate === this.parentContainer.selectedDueDate)` `"If"` here letter `I` its uppercase should be `if(node.data.dueDate === this.parentContainer.selectedDueDate)`

*And also use arrow method instead of function because `this` is getting scoped to the `function`, but `this` has access outside for arrow method*

Using the fat arrow method you can do something like:~

```
this.gridApi.forEachNode(node => {
    if(node.data.dueDate === this.parentContainer.selectedDueDate) {
       node.setSelected(true);
    }
});
```

or you need to `bind(this)` with normal function like

```
this.gridApi.forEachNode(function(node) {
    if(node.data.dueDate === this.parentContainer.selectedDueDate) {
       node.setSelected(true);
    }
}.bind(this));
```